# Defining a newcommand with sub- or superscript and avoiding "double subscript" error

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I often use shortcuts defined via `\newcommand`. However sometimes it causes a "double subscript" problem if a shortcut contains a subscript and I try to add one more subscript when using it.

I am aware of all kinds of workarounds, as illustrated in the example below. But what is the most robust way to define such shortcuts?

Example of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% define some shortcuts
\newcommand\xa{x_a}
\newcommand\xb{{x_b}}

\def\cmpto{\quad\textrm{compare to}\quad}

\begin{document}

% this produces a "double subscript" error
%\[  \xa_i   \]

This is a workaround, which produces a good result
\[    \xa{}_i \cmpto x_{ai}    \]

But still not ideal: watch the position of the superscript
\[    \xa{}_i^2 \cmpto x_{ai}^2    \]

The \verb+{x_b}+ below produces no error, but does not look good 
(watch the baseline of the subscripts)
%
\[    \xb_i \cmpto x_{bi}    \]

Also superscript does not look good
%
\[    \xb^2 \cmpto x_b^2    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works so long as you put always subscripts next to the newly defined commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newsubcommand[3]{\newcommand#1{#2\sc@sub{#3}}}
\def\sc@sub#1{\def\sc@thesub{#1}\@ifnextchar_{\sc@mergesubs}{_{\sc@thesub}}}
\def\sc@mergesubs_#1{_{\sc@thesub#1}}
\makeatother

\newsubcommand{\xa}{x}{a}

\begin{document}
$\xa$

$\xa_i x_{ai}\xa^2 x_a^2$
\end{document}
```

It might be extended to support `\xa^2_i`, but it doesn't seem a good idea to add complications.

**Explanation**
The command `\newsubcommand` defines an abbreviation where the first argument is the command to define, the second is the main letter and the third is the fixed subscript.

The macro `\xa` defined in the example will look whether the following character is `_` and, if so, it will merge the subscripts.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only modification I would suggest is `\newcommand#1{\ensuremath#2\sc@sub{#3}}`

Comment: You won't have that from me. :) I've started a campaign agaist the abuse of `\ensuremath`. :) Seriously: you gain nothing from it, in these cases.

Comment: Could you explain your statement a bit more? I thnk typing `\xa` instead of `\(\xa\)` saves my time and improves readability.

Comment: It doesn't improve readability, in my opinion. It just saves you some characters, but at the expense of clarity: math is math, text is text. For instance, my editor colors math differently: this helps readability.