# Merge double subscripts in macro with second subscript passed as argument

Tags: subscripts

I would like to make a function `\des{a}{b}` that produces the following result:

- `\des{Q}{1} > Q_1`
- `\des{Q_c}{1} > Q_{c,1}`

I have tried to adapt the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257863/merge-double-subscripts-in-macro) but I could not figure out how to put my second argument after the comma in the subscript.

This is the code I have produced:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\des{mm}{\csname riccardo_des:nn\endcsname{#1}{_}{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \riccardo_des:nn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
   { \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 } { \riccardo_dessb:n } }
   { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \sb { #3 } } }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \riccardo_dessb:n #1 
 { \sb { #1 , des } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I want to substitute `,des` in the line before the last with the second argument I pass to the `\des` function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here, I search the first argument for `_`.  If not found, I use `#1_{#2}`.  If found (breaking down `#1` as `#3_#4`), it uses `#3_{#4,#2}`.

Thanks to Mico for pointing out that comma was being set in `\scriptscriptstyle`.  EDITED to fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\des[2]{\desaux{#1}{#2}#1_\relax}
\def\desaux#1#2#3_#4\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#4\relax
    #1_{#2}
  \else
    #3_{\stripus#4,#2}
  \fi
}
\def\stripus#1_{#1}
\begin{document}
$\des{Q}{1}$

$\des{Q_c}{1}$

$Q_{c,1}$ for comparison

$\des{Q_{ab}}{c}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Based on comments of the OP, it appears that he desires interaction with `\mathbf` under certain scenarios (when `#2` is empty). and with `\bar` on demand.  While I am not sure if this could address all the needs, such things can be done directly in the `\des` macro, rather than interacting with a 2nd macro.

EDITED to also handle the bolding of greek letters (`amsbsy` added, with use of `\boldsymbol`)

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,amsbsy}
\newcommand\des[3][]{\desaux{#2}{#3}#2_\relax{#1}}
\def\desaux#1#2#3_#4\relax#5{%
  \ifx\relax#4\relax
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \boldsymbol{\mathbf{#5#1}}
    \else
      #5#1_{#2}
    \fi
  \else
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
      \boldsymbol{\mathbf{#5#3_{\stripus#4}}}
    \else
      #5#3_{\stripus#4,#2}
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\stripus#1_{#1}
\begin{document}
$\des{Q}{1}$\par
$\des{Q_c}{1}$\par
$\des{Q}{}$\par
$\des{Q_c}{}$\par
$\des[\bar]{Q}{1}$\par
$\des[\bar]{Q_c}{1}$\par
$\des[\bar]{Q}{}$\par
$\des[\bar]{Q_c}{}$

$\des{\psi}{}$\par
$\des{\psi_\alpha}{}$\par
$\des[\bar]{\psi_\alpha}{}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the typeset version of `$\des{Q_c}{1}$`, the comma between `c` and `1` seems be both too small and placed too low. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Mico You are right.  Let me work to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution fails to put the comma in this case though: \des{\mathbf{Q_c}}{1}

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin It is pretty obvious why it fails, because the first argument is wrapped in a `\mathbf`.  Not saying I can account for that, but just to point me in the right direction, should the `<comma> 1` be in `\mathbf`?

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin More properly, the `\mathbf` should be wrapped around the outside, as in `\mathbf{\des{Q_{ab}}{c}}`

Comment: I have this complicated command that return the 'quantity' #1 bold if no subscript #2 is passed or returns it non-bold with the subscript #2. Moreover #3 is another optional modifier as \bar. If my quantity #1 has a subscript I want to add the subscript #2 after a comma (and both not bold)
`\newcommandx{\myquantity}[4][1=, 2=, 3=]{\des{#3{\mkcomp{#1}{#2}}}{#2}}`
`\newcommand{\mkcomp}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\mathbf{#1}}{#1}}`

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin `#4` appears not to be used, what is the meaning of the optional argument `[1=, 2=, 3=]` which makes no sense to me?  Finally, what would be a typical or challenging usage example of `\myquantity`?

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin Please see my answer **SUPPLEMENT** to see if it can be used in lieu of your `\myquantity` logic.

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin Your question seems of XY type; you should make a new one with the full specification for the `\myquantity` command; I don't think that `\newcommandx` is the best way to go.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks! I think that your supplement covers all my cases

Comment: @egreg As suggested by you I have posted this new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444413/148167

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The suggested command does not work if the quantity is a command, for example \psi. Is it there a way to change your macro to do this?

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin Not sure what you mean.  For example, using my supplemental code, `$\des[\bar]{\psi_\alpha}{\delta}$` works just fine.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry for expressing the problem in a terrible way. The problem is that the greek letters are not put in bold if no subscript is passed. Apparrently though it is not a problem of the macro, but the fact that greek letters require \boldsymbol instead of \mathbf. Someone suggest to use \boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}} to solve this.

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin My supplement has been revised to support your request.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a LaTeX macro called `\des`, which takes two arguments and calls a Lua function called `desfn` which, in turn, does most of the work with the help of two Lua string functions (`string.find` and `string.sub`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function desfn ( u , v )
   w = u:find ( "_" )
   if w then -- found an underscore (_) char.
      tex.sprint ( u:sub(1,w-1) .. "_{" .. u:sub(w+1) .. "," .. v .. "}" )
   else
      tex.sprint ( u .. "_{" .. v .. "}" )
   end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX side code:
\newcommand\des[2]{\directlua{desfn(\luastring{#1},\luastring{#2})}}

\begin{document}
$\des{Q}{1}$ \quad $\des{Q_c}{1}$ \quad $\des{ABC_uvw}{123}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution based on LuaTeX, here by directly manipulating the math noads instead of using strings. This for example allows nesting calls to `\des` or contruction a version `\appendsub` which does not need the first argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
local oldsub
function storesub()
  local tail = tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr].tail
  oldsub = tail and tail.sub
  if oldsub then
    tail.sub = nil
  end
end
function recoversub(sep)
  if oldsub then
    local noad = node.new'noad'
    noad.nucleus = oldsub
    node.write(noad)
    oldsub = nil
    tex.sprint(sep)
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\appendsub[1]{\directlua{storesub()}_{\directlua{recoversub','}#1}}
\newcommand\des[2]{#1\appendsub{#2}}

\begin{document}
$\des{Q}{1}$ \quad $\des{Q_a}{1}$ \quad $\des{Q_{ab}}{123}$ \quad $\des{\des{Q}{abc}}{123}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Just in case there's any confusion about the ability to handle nested `\des` cases: the strings-based solution method provided in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444047/5001) typesets `$\des{\des{Q}{abc}}{123}$` (and other nested-`\des` cases) just fine as well. This is the case because the `\luastring` macro fully expands its argument. Thus, if an instance of `\des` is found in either argument of a `\des` call, it'll get expanded (and processed by `desfn`) before the "outer" `\des` gets to do its work.

Comment: For sure, it's interesting that our LuaLaTeX-based approaches can handle nested `\des` cases, whereas the approaches offered by @StevenB.Segletes and @egreg apparently can not.

Comment: @Mico Nice, I missed that `\luastring` does full expansion. I wish I could upvote your answer again :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding some code to your answer to pretty-print the Lua code block. Feel free to revert if you don't like the result.

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit regular expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\des}{mm}
 {
  \simone_des:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__simone_des_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__simone_des_second_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simone_des:nn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \cD_ } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__simone_des_first_tl { #1 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__simone_des_second_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN
     { \cD_(.*)\Z } % whatever after _
     { \cD_\cB\{\1,\u{l__simone_des_second_tl}\cE\} }
     \l__simone_des_first_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__simone_des_first_tl
   }
   {#1\sb{#2}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\des{Q}{1}$

$\des{Q_1}{c}$

\end{document}
```

[image]