# Best way to craft custom command with 4 optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

I would like to make a command that produces the following results

```
\myquantity[Q]
\myquantity[Q][i]
\myquantity[Q][][j]
\myquantity[Q][i][j]
\myquantity[Q][i][j][\bar]
\myquantity[Q][][][\bar]
\myquantity[Q][][][\tilde]
\myquantity[Q_c][i][j][\bar]
```

[image: Result]

My current solution is the following

```
\newcommandx{\myquantity}[4][1=, 2=, 3=, 4=]{
  \des[#4]{#1}{#3}(\lambda_{#2})}
```

where `\des` is the command in the supplement of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444043/148167).

Is there a simpler way to obtain the same result?

Comment: If you really want this use xparse. But 4 optional arguments are probably not the best markup.

Comment: Did you redefine `\lambda` for that to work? If so, *why*?

Comment: If one of the answers below solves your problem, could you mark that one as accepted? Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Skillmon It was a typo. I edited the code now.

Comment: @TeXnician Using newcommandx is something I understand as opposite to writing the intricated code proposed in the other answers, that is why I choose it. How can I let the first argument not be optional?

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin `\newcommandx` seems attractive, but it's buggy.

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin I did suggest xparse with `\NewDocumentCommand`, but not `\newcommandx`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to argue that having four optional arguments is not very semantic. I would use a command with a `key=value` optional argument.

```
\myquantity[Q_c][i][j][\bar]
```

is a lot less readable than

```
\myquantity[accent=\bar,subscript={c,j},lambda subscript=i]{Q}
```

although the latter might be using a bit too long keys, I hope you agree it is easier to understand.

The following MWE gives an example of your desired command, using a key-value argument. If you indeed think the keys are too long, you can always change them what you find descriptive enough.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@myquantity@subscript
\newif\if@myquantity@lambdasubscript
\pgfkeys{
    my quantity/.cd,
        accent/.code={\let\@myquantity@accent#1},
        accent=\relax,
        subscript/.code={\def\@myquantity@subscript{#1}\@myquantity@subscripttrue},
        lambda subscript/.code={\def\@myquantity@lambdasubscript{#1}\@myquantity@lambdasubscripttrue},
}
\newcommand{\myquantity}[2][]{%
    \@myquantity@subscriptfalse
    \@myquantity@lambdasubscriptfalse
    \pgfkeys{my quantity/.cd,#1}%
    \if@myquantity@subscript%
        \@myquantity@accent{#2}_{\@myquantity@subscript}%
    \else%
        \@myquantity@accent{\mathbf{#2}}%
    \fi%
    (\lambda%
    \if@myquantity@lambdasubscript
        _{\@myquantity@lambdasubscript}%
    \fi)%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{lll}
            \myquantity{Q} &
            \myquantity[lambda subscript=i]{Q} &
            \myquantity[subscript=j]{Q}\\
            \myquantity[subscript=j,lambda subscript=i]{Q} &
            \myquantity[accent=\bar,subscript=j,lambda subscript=i]{Q} &
            \myquantity[accent=\bar]{Q} \\
            \myquantity[accent=\tilde]{Q} &
            \myquantity[accent=\bar,subscript={c,j},lambda subscript=i]{Q}
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can I find a reference of the commands used in your answer?

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin the keys can be defined with the `pgfkeys` package which is automatically loaded when you're using Tikz or `pgf`. You can find more information on the key management in chapter 82 (page 875) of the [Tikz/PGF manual](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) .

Answer (score 4):

Four optional arguments require too much care in input. Besides, one of them is mandatory and the last one refers to the mandatory argument, so it should be specified first.

My idea is

```
\myq[<optional decoration>]{<variable>}[<optional coordinate>](<optional subscript)
```

so there is no need to specify empty optional arguments.

What do the macros do? First I look for `_` in the optional argument, because this should not be part of `\mathbf` when no coordinate appears. For this purpose, `\regex_split:nnN` is available: if no `_` is found, the sequence will have just one item, otherwise it will have two (what comes before `_` and what comes after).

Then it's a matter of checking whether the coordinate is specified, in order to decide for `\mathbf` or not.

The `<decoration>` should be a math accent command; it defaults to `\use:n`, which means “output the argument” (the classical `\@firstofone`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno,fleqn]{amsmath} % the options are just to better show the output
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myq}{
  O{\use:n} % decoration for the main variable
  m         % main variable
  o         % coordinate
  d()       % subscript to \lambda
 }
 {
  % separate off the possible subscript to the variable;
  % item 1 contains the variable, item 2 the subscript
  \regex_split:nnN { \cD_ } { #2 } \l_simone_myq_var_seq
  % make the subscript
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_simone_myq_var_seq = 1 }
   {% no subscript in #2
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
     { #1 { \mathbf{#2} } }
     { #1 { #2 } \sb { #3 } }
   }
   {% subscript in #2
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
     {
      #1 { \mathbf{\seq_item:Nn \l_simone_myq_var_seq { 1 }} } % base
      \sb { \seq_item:Nn \l_simone_myq_var_seq { 2 } }
     }
     {
      #1 { \seq_item:Nn \l_simone_myq_var_seq { 1 } } % base
      \sb { \seq_item:Nn \l_simone_myq_var_seq { 2 } , #3 }
     }
   }
  ( \lambda\IfValueT{#4}{\sb{#4}} )
 }

\seq_new:N \l_simone_myq_var_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\myq{Q} \\
\myq[\bar]{Q} \\
\myq{Q}[i] \\
\myq{Q}(j) \\
\myq{Q}[i](j) \\
\myq[\tilde]{Q}(j) \\
\myq[\tilde]{Q}[i](j) \\
\myq{Q_c} \\
\myq[\bar]{Q_c} \\
\myq{Q_c}[i] \\
\myq{Q_c}(j) \\
\myq{Q_c}[i](j) \\
\myq[\tilde]{Q_c}(j) \\
\myq[\tilde]{Q_c}[i](j)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can I find a reference of the commands used in your answer?

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`