# Producing a triangle diagram with sections

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

Hi, I am fairly new to LaTeX. I am trying to create the equilateral triangle shown in this sketch, I have provided the code for what I have so far but am stuck at this stage, is there a simpler way? Is this the best package to use? If so what is the next step?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=north]{$A$}
  -- (4,0) node[anchor=north]{$B$}
  -- (2,4) node[anchor=south]{$C$}
   -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We can't help you with the decision for the *best* package, because there are several packages that are good for drawing lines and you may even paint a triangle in picture mode. But what do you mean with next step? You know about the concept of coordinates, so you just have to calculate the positions of the other points and equally use `\draw`. So please specify the question you need help with.

Comment: @Fideo If one of the answers below solves your problem, could you mark that one as accepted? Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\foreach` loops and polar coordinates for this.

The first `\foreach` is

```
\foreach \angle/\label in {90/C,210/A,330/B}{
    \coordinate[label={\angle:\label}] (\label) at (\angle:2){};
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
\coordinate[label={210:A}] (A) at ({2*cos(210)},{2*sin(210)});
\coordinate[label={330:B}] (B) at ({2*cos(330)},{2*sin(330)});
\coordinate[label={ 90:C}] (C) at ({2*cos( 90)},{2*sin( 90)});
```

Notice that the polar coordinates are equal to expressing the `x` as `radius*cos(angle)` and the `y` as `radius*sin(angle)`. I often find this notation easier.

The second `\foreach` is

```
\foreach [count=\i] \angle in {240,180,...,-60}{
    \node at (\angle:0.75){\i};
}
```

Which is already saving us quite some work, because it is equivalent to

```
\node at ({0.75*cos(240)},{0.75*sin(240)}){1};
\node at ({0.75*cos(180)},{0.75*sin(180)}){2};
\node at ({0.75*cos(120)},{0.75*sin(120)}){3};
\node at ({0.75*cos( 60)},{0.75*sin( 60)}){4};
\node at ({0.75*cos(  0)},{0.75*sin(  0)}){5};
\node at ({0.75*cos(-60)},{0.75*sin(-60)}){6};
```

Which is just cumbersome to type in manually.

The command `\draw (A) -- coordinate (AB) (B) -- coordinate (BC) (C) -- coordinate (CA) cycle;` is used to draw the edges of the triangle, and at the same time defines the coordinates `(AB)`, `(BC)` and `(CA)` that lie between the corners.

The last thing remaining is to draw the lines from the middle of the edges to the opposite corners, which is done with

```
\draw (A) -- (BC);
\draw (B) -- (CA);
\draw (C) -- (AB);
```

Because we already defined the coordinates while drawing the edges.

If you want to use mathematical expressions inside the coordinate definitions (e.g. `sin(90)`), you have to enclose the expression in braces, because Tikz will get confused at the parentheses inside the expression.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \angle/\label in {90/C,210/A,330/B}{
            \node[coordinate,label={\angle:\label}] (\label) at (\angle:2){};
        }
        \draw (A) -- coordinate (AB) (B) -- coordinate (BC) (C) -- coordinate (CA) cycle;

        \draw (A) -- (BC);
        \draw (B) -- (CA);
        \draw (C) -- (AB);

        \foreach [count=\i] \angle in {240,180,...,-60}{
            \node at (\angle:0.75){\i};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The fact that the triangle is a equilateral directly follows from using polar coordinates with the same radius and the same angle difference.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Really just for fun. **EDIT**: Simplified the evaluation of `\Z` and removed the overshooting of the segment lines, *very* big thanks to @MaxSnippe, and moved the alphabetic labels a bit closer to the corners.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\newcounter{cheat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=5cm,regular polygon,draw,regular polygon sides=3,outer
sep=0pt] (a) {};
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(1+mod(\X,3))},
evaluate=\X as \Z using {int(1+mod(1+\X,3))}] in {1,2,3}
{\draw ($(a.corner \X)!0.5!(a.corner \Y)$) -- (a.corner \Z);
\setcounter{cheat}{\Z}
\node at ($1.1*(a.corner \X)$) {\Alph{cheat}};
}
\foreach \X[count=\Y] in {240,180,...,-60}
{\node at (\X:1) {\Y};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever, definitely +1 ! Looks even better when the `outer sep` of the node is set to 0. (You could also evaluate `\Z` as `{int(1+mod(1+\X,3))}`).

Comment: @MaxSnippe Thanks! I think the `outer sep` does not really have an impact, but if you mean that one should decrease the `1.2` in `\node at ($1.2*(a.corner \X)$) {\Alph{cheat}};` I agree. And I agree with the other statement, of course. (BTW, I am really impressed by [this answer of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444415/121799), I was not aware that this is so simple and elegant. ;-)

Comment: I actually meant that the angle bisector lines *slightly* protrude the node (see https://imgur.com/a/Xf0mlbm). Thanks! I strongly believe the key-value approach can really open up a lot of possibilities, especially with optional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) + [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
path T;
T = for t=7 step 4 until 15: 72 dir 30t -- endfor cycle;
for i=0 upto 2:
  draw point i of T -- point 3/2 + i of T withcolor 1/2 white;
  label("$" & char (65+i) & "$", 9/8 point i of T);
endfor
for i=1 upto 6: 
  label("$" & decimal i & "$", 2/3 point 1/3 (2 - 2i + ceiling 1/2i) of T);
endfor
draw T;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```