# Awkward spacing with primes and commas in subscripts

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Putting primes and commas together in subscript results in awkward spacing --- the space between a primed item and the following comma is exceedingly large compared to the space after.

The same happens with any superscripts in subscripts, but with primes this is especially jarring.

This does not occur outside of subscripts. Is there any simple remedy?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
{
\Huge
\[
  f_{a,b',c}\quad a, b', c
\]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `f_{a,b'\!,c}` would be an easy fix. Actually this does happen in textstyle also; it's just not as noticible. You can use `a, b'\!, c` there as well.

Comment: Just a simple curiosity. Why do you use \Huge{...} out the math-formula?

Comment: @SandyG: sure, sure, but I meant something less ad hoc. Doing this sort of thing once is okay, but maintaining a longer document where you have lots of primed subscripts this way would be a nightmare.

Comment: @Sebastiano: So it's easier to see the result without zooming.

Comment: @tomasz Ah....I had not understood the reason :-)

Comment: the braces after `\Huge` though are misleading as the font size applies to the whole document not just the brace group, although not clear here as there is nothing after `}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, I did not know that. I had actually never used the size commands before. I fixed the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use from `amsmath`, the command `\negthickspace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  f_{a,b'\negthickspace,c}\quad a, b', c
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better (and also a bit nicer than the vanilla \! solution), but I was wondering if there is a solution that would not require typing an extra command for every single prime comma combination (like a package that would just magically do this).

Comment: @tomasz It is possibile but or we use a \newcommand or we must use very complicated strategies that I don't know about.

Comment: You can see, for example, here in this link with any package that I not know the mechanicism: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444038/merge-double-subscripts-in-macro-with-second-subscript-passed-as-argument or